# Dynamic Blog Post with Ajax Jquery JSon

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

`enter code here`I'm pretty new to web developing and currently working on a blog project where I want to load every blogpost with data which is coming from a json file. I can read and show the data on a table. But I want to show it on a specific template multiple time for each post.From the code below it shows only the last post.

**Heres my html template.**

```
    <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="#">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata" style="border:none;">
            <a id="author" class="mr-2" href="#"></a>reviewed
            <a id="restaurent" class="mr-2" href="#"> </a>
            <small id ="reviewdate" class="text-muted"></small> 
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="border:none;">
            <div class="row ">
                <div id="photo" class="col-md-3">                       
                    <img src="#" class="w-100">                      
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 px-1">
                    <div class="card-block px-1">
                        <h4><a id ="title" class="article-title" href="#"></a> </h4>
                        <p id="body" class="article-content"></p>
                        <div id ="tag" class="row">                              
                            <p class="article-content"></p>                              
                        </div>
                        <div  class="'row">                               
                            <p id="item" class="article-content"></p>                              
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

and my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') == null) {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:55407/User/signin";
        }

        $('#linkClose').click(function () {
            $('#divError').hide('fade');
        });

        $('#errorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            window.location.href = "Login.html";
        });

        //$('#btnLoadEmployees').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:55407/api/Review/GetReviewPosts',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                        + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#divData').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#tblBody').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#author').text(value.ApplicationUser.Name);
                        $('#restaurent').text(value.RestaurantOrPalce.Id);
                        $('#reviewdate').text(value.TimePosted);
                        $('#photo').text(value.Photos.Id);
                        $('#title').text(value.PostTitle);
                        $('#body').text(value.PostBody);
                        $('#tag').text(value.Tags[0].Name);
                        $('#item').text(value.Items[0].Name);
                    });
                },
            });
        });
    //});
</script>
```

My json data. Its just one post. But there will be multiple post with same format.

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "Posts": [],
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Burger",
            "Type": "fastfood",
            "Timestamp": "2020-09-03T00:00:00",
            "FoodOrTravel": 1
        },
        {
            "Posts": [],
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Pizza",
            "Type": "italianfood",
            "Timestamp": "2020-12-30T00:00:00",
            "FoodOrTravel": 1
        }
    ],
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Posts": [],
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "abc",
            "TimeStamp": "2020-08-28T00:00:00",
            "FOodOrTravel": 1
        },
        {
            "Posts": [],
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "bbb",
            "TimeStamp": "2020-08-28T00:00:00",
            "FOodOrTravel": 1
        }
    ],
    "Id": 6,
    "PostTitle": "Bekar khatni",
    "IsOfferOrPlanned": false,
    "IsRecommended": false,
    "RestaurantOrPalce": {
        "Id": 1,
        "TotalRecommendation": 2,
        "ApplicationUser": {
            "Claims": [],
            "Logins": [],
            "Roles": [],
            "Photo": null,
            "Location": null,
            "CreatedAt": null,
            "Gender": 3,
            "ProfileTitle": null,
            "ProfileTitleId": null,
            "Badge": null,
            "BadgeId": null,
            "Contact": 0,
            "ProfileType": null,
            "IsBanned": false,
            "Name": "ayan1",
            "Email": "mussh1@gmail.com",
            "EmailConfirmed": false,
            "PasswordHash": "ABu1hMOulbTpAGGP4iF709wBOTILaKByMMsB3rTQwEmI4H/W4f8kUnIBG7IliWuBFA==",
            "SecurityStamp": "a28d4096-3d96-403e-a4ae-f78fd8b2230a",
            "PhoneNumber": null,
            "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
            "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
            "LockoutEndDateUtc": null,
            "LockoutEnabled": false,
            "AccessFailedCount": 0,
            "Id": "5edb41be-ad53-481a-99c3-df19ab9ead91",
            "UserName": "mussh1g"
        },
        "TotalReviews": 3,
        "RestOrPlace": 1,
        "Location": null
    },
    "ApplicationUser": {
        "Claims": [],
        "Logins": [],
        "Roles": [],
        "Photo": null,
        "Location": null,
        "CreatedAt": null,
        "Gender": 3,
        "ProfileTitle": null,
        "ProfileTitleId": null,
        "Badge": null,
        "BadgeId": null,
        "Contact": 0,
        "ProfileType": null,
        "IsBanned": false,
        "Name": "ayan1",
        "Email": "mussh1@gmail.com",
        "EmailConfirmed": false,
        "PasswordHash": "ABu1hMOulbTpAGGP4iF709wBOTILaKByMMsB3rTQwEmI4H/W4f8kUnIBG7IliWuBFA==",
        "SecurityStamp": "a28d4096-3d96-403e-a4ae-f78fd8b2230a",
        "PhoneNumber": null,
        "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
        "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
        "LockoutEndDateUtc": null,
        "LockoutEnabled": false,
        "AccessFailedCount": 0,
        "Id": "5edb41be-ad53-481a-99c3-df19ab9ead91",
        "UserName": "mussh1g"
    },
    "ApplicationUserId": "5edb41be-ad53-481a-99c3-df19ab9ead91",
    "Reactions": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "PostId": 6,
            "ApplicationUser": {
                "Claims": [],
                "Logins": [],
                "Roles": [],
                "Photo": null,
                "Location": null,
                "CreatedAt": null,
                "Gender": 3,
                "ProfileTitle": null,
                "ProfileTitleId": null,
                "Badge": null,
                "BadgeId": null,
                "Contact": 0,
                "ProfileType": null,
                "IsBanned": false,
                "Name": "ayan1",
                "Email": "mussh1@gmail.com",
                "EmailConfirmed": false,
                "PasswordHash": "ABu1hMOulbTpAGGP4iF709wBOTILaKByMMsB3rTQwEmI4H/W4f8kUnIBG7IliWuBFA==",
                "SecurityStamp": "a28d4096-3d96-403e-a4ae-f78fd8b2230a",
                "PhoneNumber": null,
                "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
                "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
                "LockoutEndDateUtc": null,
                "LockoutEnabled": false,
                "AccessFailedCount": 0,
                "Id": "5edb41be-ad53-481a-99c3-df19ab9ead91",
                "UserName": "mussh1g"
            },
            "ApplicationUserId": "5edb41be-ad53-481a-99c3-df19ab9ead91",
            "IsLiked": 1,
            "IsHelpfull": 2
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "PostId": 6,
            "ApplicationUser": null,
            "ApplicationUserId": "6f138524-1dfd-4564-bbe3-8e326656d5b4",
            "IsLiked": 2,
            "IsHelpfull": 1
        }
    ],
    "Photos": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "PostId": 6,
            "Caption": "hmmm",
            "Url": "cdha",
            "TimeStamp": "2020-08-28T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "PostComments": null,
    "TimePosted": "2020-08-28T00:00:00",
    "PostBody": "fdhjjfg",
    "FoodOrTravel": 1,
    "Stars": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Food": 4.5,
        "Environment": 4.5,
        "Service": 4.0,
        "Cleanliness": 5.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON data you get from the success response of your ajax ?

Comment: I have added the json data format.

Comment: How will you differentiate each blog post data with JSON data to be added ?

Comment: Im going to add only certain field of the post. For example I only want to show the "ApplicationUser.Name", "RestaurantOrPalce.Name","photo url", "PostTitle", "PostBody", "tags" and "items". I put "id" field with similer name on each html elements.

Comment: Yeah i understand that. But HOW will you know that this photo URL OR title belong to which blog post (article) on your page - You do not have any unique `ID` or name for each blog to be campared with the api blog data - you know what i mean ?

Comment: Im getting hard time understanding your question sorry. This json file is coming from database through api call where post id, title and image url are stored in same row.And as for me , I'm going to show all post one after another.

Comment: I believe what @AlwaysHelping is trying to tell you is that the ID fields for which you are setting the values are not distinct in the HTML by blog post so you have a problem where the AJAX is inserting the value for the element with ID "author" but there is only 1 "author" ID in the HTML. Therefore, all posts in your loop are setting values to the same exact HTML element and the last post is winning since it is the last to set a value. You need a way in the HTML to distinguish post 1's "author" from post 87's "author" in order to have them all displayed.